# Как создать иконки для кнопок

Tags: android, kotlin

Такая проблема, скачивании с сайтов с иконками иконки огромные, и решал я это с помощью iconsize в разметке, но мне сейчас нужно установить иконку программно, а iconsize там нет.

Еще хотел спросить иконки с сайтов дозволено использовать или их нужно, как то редактировать, что б за руку не поймали

Comment: в каком формате вы скачиваете с сайта изображение?

Comment: png расширение или про какой формат вы говорили

Comment: да именно о нем, качайте в svg и там можно будет у картинки редактировать размер и цвета и тп